# Is there a point in improving a completely unclear and badly formatted question?

Tags: discussion, edits, low-quality-posts

<strike>[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672057/set-up-for-cycle-vba-language)</strike> got me thinking...

Question is now deleted but here is a screenshot for reference

[image]

Seeing the caps in the title I immediately went into the edit mode and started editing the question by removing caps. Then I started actually reading it as I was editing and realized the question makes no sense at all... it's poor, bad formatted, using caps, requesting things etc. A complete mess.

I am not able to rescue it from getting downvoted and closed therefore;

Is there even a point in editing it even though this questions is going to be downvoted and closed? Do we really have to be *that* generous when it comes to VLQ questions?

Are there any general guidelines when to improve a question and when not to bother?

Comment: when I have time, I often edit questions like this, to help close and delete voters see it more clearly that it deserves closure and deletion

Comment: I edit questions not to save them from being closed, but to attempt to improve them and help the new users learn how to use the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question you use as an example is hard to understand and it seems clear that even once "fixed" it will remain a poor question that will be closed anyway (at least 3 closing reasons would apply: too broad, unclear, lacks sufficient information).

There are only that many hours in a day - so instead of spending 10 minutes fixing a question that is essentially beyond repair, you should probably fix 10 questions/answers that have more value.

I'd just downvote and close as "unclear...".

Comment: this particular one is used as an example, but what would be the general guidelines for figuring out when to fix a question or not fix it?

Comment: @mehow I'd say if it's going to be [a good candidate for deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete) it's not worth fixing.

Comment: An extra warning for users who, like myself, have under 2K rep: [attempting to improve unsalvageable questions can result in getting your edit rejected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307482/why-is-there-not-an-edit-rejection-reason-to-cover-turd-polishing)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much effort is required to improve an VLQ question. Prior to its deletion, this post would have been slightly improved by changing the all-caps shouting to ordinary paragraph text. That would not have been nearly enough to save it, but importantly this sends a notification message to the poster as to how the community likes questions to be presented.

It would be interesting to see if edit alerts have an effect, statistically speaking, on users who write poor quality posts. In the absence of data, one would presume that is their purpose, so if you can make a speedy edit and explain it using the edit reason, the OP in each case *may* modify their behaviour.