# Should low quality novice questions be deleted?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, vote-to-delete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085965/calculate-and-print-piecewise-function

This question is a typical novice question. Or maybe a bit worse than typical. It started as:

> ## Please help me write a Java program
>
> Please help me write a Java program that calculates and prints the equation on the picture below . I'm required to do it in JDK 7 with Neatbeans. I tried to do it myself but it doesn't seem to be right . Here is the equation :http://s8.postimg.org/g5lizydad/6_1.png
>   Here's what I tried to do : http://s18.postimg.org/ub9nx0vo9/image.png
>   Thanks in advance for your help

Clearly, it needed a lot of work. Bad title. No code. No error message. Image links. It was quickly, and deservingly, downvoted and put on hold.

I tried to clean up the question, putting the first image inline (which new askers aren't allowed to do) and typing up the code in the second one. But despite my edits, the question was not just closed, it was deleted.

> ## Calculate and print piecewise function
>
> Please help me write a Java program that calculates and prints the equation on the picture below. I'm required to do it in JDK 7 with Neatbeans. I tried to do it myself but it doesn't seem to be right. Here is the equation:
>
> [image]
>
> Here's what I tried to do:
>
> ```
> /**
>  *
>  * @author Luka
>  */
> public class JavaApplication9 {
>
>     /**
>      * @param args the command line arguments
>      */
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         // TODO code application logic here
>         int x=0;
>         int y;
>         if(x>=-5);
>         System.out.println(int y="x*x");
>         else
>         System.out.println(int y="-x");
>     }
> }
> ```

Isn't deleting a bit much? Deleting the question so quickly gave the OP no time to respond to the "unclear what you're asking" closure reason. The purpose of putting questions on hold, in labeling them "on hold" rather than "closed", is to push posters to improve their questions and get them reopened, no?

I thought deleting is for questions that cannot be improved, like spam or job postings or blatantly off topic posts.

Part of me wonders if the question was deleted because folks were annoyed by the code being **so bad**. Which it is. It's really bad. The OP's clearly *just starting out*. Is that delete worthy, though?

Comment: Can that be improved though? The OP clearly doesn't understand even the most basic parts of programming. Seems more like they weren't paying attention in class and just threw some words and characters together that just *look* like code.

Comment: I suppose one hypothetical benefit to the OP of deletion is that it prevents any more downvotes (was on -12)  But without knowing the actual formula for question banning I don't know that this is actually the case that additional downvotes would make matters any worse for them.

Comment: I vote to delete when the post is only attracting more noise and is not likely to ever be made into a proper question. Rude feedback, argumentation about what makes something on-topic or not, etc. are all noise and qualify a post for fast-tracked deletion.

Comment: I agree with @animuson and adding to this, the only possible answer to such a trivial question is spoon feeding the OP. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Can that be improved though?" -- Is it *likely* to be improved? Heck, no. I'm not naive. Questions are rarely ever made better. But is it *possible*? Yes, it's possible. [Here's an example of a very low quality question that was actually completely fixed up after being put on hold.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070920/should-a-mutator-return-a-bool-or-is-it-an-unnecessary-sanity-check)

Comment: An important reason to delete questions is to stop them from further occupying the time of SO users.  Like yours.  The only thing that really went wrong here is that it didn't get deleted fast enough :)  If you think the question is important then just ask it yourself.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Huge difference. That user had a ton more information that he actually could provide. The question was vague and needed more detail - that's something that can be very easily fixed. What other information are you expecting the user to provide in this case? From what I can tell, they don't know anything about programming, so I'm not exactly expecting them to provide anything they haven't provided already. In my opinion, this question is the definition of unsalvagebale and should be deleted.

Comment: @animuson Not that I'd dissagree with you, but isn't deleting based on asker's (assumed) skills against the site policy? "Never look at person, always look at post."

Comment: Wait are we deleting this guys question solely based on him beign a beginner at programming? So one minute there is a indepth discussion on how to stop elitism in this community but here we are now all saying this question from a noob who has clearly put some effort into this (code sample says it all) needs to be held/deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete it.  It would probably have been a good thing to delete it even sooner than it was.

Recognize that the question is going to get closed and down voted, and the roomba is likely going to come by and delete it at some point.  If you are a kind soul and want to preserve the OP from question bans and rate limits, deleting the question when its at -3 is likely less ban inducing than when it is at -12 (and gets deleted).

Consider who it is going to help *next*.  The question in its original form was very poor.  Your edit did help it quite a bit (though I will point out a trend from people posting homework of using screen shots rather than the problem description or code so that it is harder for their instructors to find them).

A much better question could be asked.  There is currently only one question tagged [piecewise + java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piecewise+java).  You might consider writing a self-answered question in that problem space so that the next poorly asked piecewise problem could be closed as a dup of that one.

My tests for delete votes elsewhere is (and do recognize that these criteria are community dependent - what goes for elsewhere isn't what goes for all other sites):

- Are the answers going to help anyone else? or is it something that is just cluttering up results?
- Is the question at least the minimum quality that I expect for the site?

  - If not, can it be improved to meet this minimum?

These are the two major questions that I look at when casting a delete vote.

Note that "no time to respond" bit - people can edit the deleted post and then flag it to be undeleted, or bring it to the attention of others via meta or chat.  On the other hand I've seen posts from years ago where someone asks a clarifying comment and the OP says "let me get back to you on that" and never shows up again (and those *aren't* in down voted questions that would get deleted).

Personally, I think there should be a great culling of things closed as too localized from days of old that will never be fixed or help someone else even if they do get fixed) and a close look at those "cannot be reproduced or a simple typographical error" from more days.

A key consideration in this all, however, is the question of <del>what Stack Overflow is not</del> what types of things Stack Overflow does well and what it does poorly.  SO does not do tutorials, or hand holding while walking through code well.  Trying to do it doesn't work.  It makes a mess and leads other people to try get tutoring help on the site again and again.

Delete it.  Its not going to help anyone as it is written other than the person who posted it, and they need *other* help at learning how to ask a proper question and debugging on their own more than they need the answer to the question.  Leaving it will let someone else think that its ok (it doesn't matter how down voted it gets if it gets an answer to the homework problem due in a few hours).

Answer (score 19):

The question was quite horrible, essentially it is just code begging with a picture attached. They posted a screen shot of some nonsense code, which does nothing but demonstrating that the OP is clueless about programming. So there is no doubt that the question should be down-voted and closed.

Normally you would let the OP get a chance to improve the question, but as someone pointed out, how can they do that when they don't even know programming? Please note that Stack Overflow is a site for professional- and enthusiast *programmers*. Since the question holds no value for anyone, I don't see why it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Exactly. When I look at a question, I ask myself, is this something a professional or an enthusiast would ask? If not, I downvote, flag and move on.

Comment: ++ and John, sorry but you have just wasted your time trying to fix that question. [Been there done that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254955/is-there-a-point-in-improving-a-completely-unclear-and-bad-formatted-questions)

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't deleting a bit much?

It is a bit much in that it is a waste of time by the people voting to delete. It is also a waste of time by the people voting to undelete. If left alone that question would be [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256019/what-if-anything-happens-to-questions-with-a-negative-score) by the system for having such a low score.

Once a question has more than a few downvotes and is closed, it is overwhelmingly likely to be doomed no matter what you do. The question closure reasons encourage people to improve their questions, which is really a joke, because no matter what the OP does, no-one who downvoted and voted to close ever comes back to undownvote and vote to reopen. Telling people to "improve" their questions in such cases is just busy work to stop them from bothering anyone else by asking again. From an OP's point of view the best thing to do to get an answer is delete the question (accepting the point towards the question ban) and ask again, but everyone keeps quiet about that, because after all, we don't really want such shitty questions around.

TL;DR: Such questions are doomed, so it doesn't matter what you do.

Comment: This had some truth to it three years ago, but with the reopen queue any closed question that actually gets fixed up has a *very* good chance of getting reopened and therefore not deleted.  Now most people don't bother to try fixing up bad questions, partly because, like you, they just *assume* that it's pointless despite the fact that it's not.

Comment: @Servy On the other hand, while the review queue does work, people who might be willing to answer _still_ won't bother looking at a heavily downvoted question. Unless you have data saying otherwise, of course. Unfortunately, I'm not able to write up a good SEDE query.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're going to have to support that assertion, because that's not what I've seen.

Comment: @Servy [I have not found the reopen queue to work well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270282/close-votes-are-vanishing).

Comment: @Boann That's about the closeing queue, not the reopen queue.  Your close votes were aging out because there aren't enough people casting close votes to actually close all of the content on this site that really should be closed.  The reopen queue on the other hand ends up sitting close to zero  most of the time and very rarely actually ages review tasks.

Comment: @Servy The reopen queue has exactly the same bug. Read the comments.

Comment: @Boann the delete votes become necessary once someone posts something that gets accepted pointing out the missing semicolon or the like.

Comment: @Boann What bug?  There is no bug.  You're noticing close votes aging.  It's not a bug, it's built into the system that close votes age out.  It's possible for reopen votes to age out, but since the reopen queue doesn't get behind the way the close vote queue does, very few reopen votes actually end up aging out ever.

Comment: @Servy It looks like a bug and it walks like a bug. Maybe it's not a bug but it's doing a stellar impression of one.

Comment: @Boann So because you don't understand the feature you're calling it a bug?  Or is it because you don't like the feature that you're calling it a bug?

Comment: @Servy I do understand how the feature works. I don't understand the mentality of the people who implemented it. I'm calling it a bug because it's counterproductive and aggravating behavior.

Comment: @Boann A feature working as intended that you don't like is not a bug.  The site functioning in a way contrary to its design is a bug.  If you don't like the feature then that's fine, say you don't like the feature.  Calling it a bug just because you don't like it just makes you look bad.

Comment: That would be a [misfeature](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/m/misfeature.html) then.  (Related term: [wart](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/w/wart.html) and [miswart](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/m/miswart.html) - see [feature](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/f/feature.html) for how they all sort out).

Comment: @Servy I'll call it a bug because it's a serious problem that should be fixed. It's ridiculous to trick people into thinking they can vote to close or reopen, when the system sneaks along a few days later to delete their votes. You said yourself that improved questions can be reopened, but you're saying it's not a bug when reopen votes on reasonable questions are just deleted.

Comment: @Boann Once again, just because you don't like a feature doesn't make it a bug.  It's a feature you don't like.  And once again, reopen votes pretty much never actually age out, so your assertion that they do, in practice, is just wrong.  If you don't like the fact that close votes age away then say that you don't like the fact that close votes age away, not that it has any bearing on the subject at hand.

Comment: @Servy reopen votes *do* age out.  On P.SE in 10k tools I've watched posts have 1, then 2, (get kicked out of the review queue with leaved closed), then 3, then 2, then 1, and then disappear from the tools.  This is aging out of reopen votes. It is in part a question of how many people are casting them and how willing someone is to give a question a second chance.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, and that's demonstrating reopen votes aging for exactly the right reasons, other people looked at the post and decided that it shouldn't be reopened.  The votes aren't aging out without anyone even looking at the question to evaluate it.