# Is it ok to answer downvoted questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have come across a few questions , mostly by new accounts or guest accounts, which lack proper structure and/or are difficult to understand. Such questions get downvoted ASAP (amassing -6 to -7 votes in a matter of minutes). A few people still comment trying to get the author of the question to give more details or to try and understand what he really wants.   I have noticed that quite a few times the question has comments where people try and solve the issue but it has no answer. Is it because it is against community rules to answer such questions? Since I am a new user such questions can be a good opportunity to gain some reputation. Or will the answer be considered rep hunting and downvoted ?

NOTE: I can't seem to find the original post that prompted me to ask this here.

Comment: There's nothing against the rules about answering a downvoted question, regardless of how heavily downvoted it is.

Comment: But someone might downvote your answer to discourage encouraging bad askers.

Comment: @bmargulies:  If the answer is good, though, why would a downvote even make sense?

Comment: I didn't say it necessarily made sense.

Comment: Upvoted answers prevent even blatantly off-topic closed questions from being automatically deleted. Downvotes help ensure the roomba can do its job.

Comment: @bmargulies, you don't think it makes sense because you believe it is meant to *discourage bad askers*. That's wrong, it's to discourage bad *answerers* (but some aspects of both problems do overlap). Also keep in mind discouraging questioners is "free", whereas discouraging answerers takes one rep per discouragement (which is still quite worth it IMHO).

Comment: There's a gold badge, ["Reversal"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) for getting a score of +20 for an answer to a question with a score of -5. Of course it's awarded only for a *really good* answer to a bad question, and presumably not meant to encourage posting mediocre answers to bad questions.

Comment: @KeithThompson: And considering how few Q&A which awarded those are still not deleted, those don't seem to really work out. Considering some of those answers, the good answer often is something along the lines of "For these reasons all your question is really bad."

Comment: One example answer which granted a reversal badge: "You are cheating... this is a question from the coursera's R programming course" Or "You have 2 main functions there can only be one." Or a comment on such an answer: "My sarcasm-meter went off the chart here." None of those really worth preserving. (Yes, there are a few lonely pearls, no rule without exception.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a point in improving a completely unclear and bad formatted questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254955/is-there-a-point-in-improving-a-completely-unclear-and-bad-formatted-questions)

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that this question isn't heavily downvoted with lots of answers.

Comment: Quite commonly such questions are deleted if there is no accepted answer. You really not going to gain any reputation points on such questions - if your main goal is reputation - spend your time on questions that make sense.

Comment: @KeithThompson Most of the times the "Reversal" badge doesn't encourage what it is supposed to encourage. As far as I have seen, the answerer doesn't get the badge because he changes the opinion about the qustion or because he sees some point that other downvoters failed to see, but he actually encouraged the downvoters' opinion and got an upvote for his answer

Comment: How else are you going to get the `Reversal` badge?

Comment: Sometimes you get Downvoted because of not working solutions to your problem... and if you hint at it the "helper" deletes his answer and downvote your question (happened to me -.-)

Comment: My experience with adding comments or answers to downvoted questions is that you (the answerer or commenter) also get "dinged" on your point count! I was very surprised to see that happen, since I was trying to help. In this case the question was marked as "too general" but the question was still valid and there was a reasonable answer. Regardless, since that incident I no longer touch those questions because the number of points lost was not worth the effort. :(

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There's nothing in the rules that prevents people from answering downvoted questions.  However:

1. Heavily downvoted questions are removed from the front page, and are unlikely to get any more attention to attract new votes.
2. The community doesn't like people answering bad questions, and may downvote your answer just because of this.
3. When a person asks an unclear question, it's often indicative that they won't understand your answer, even if you understand their question.
4. You can often be answering the wrong question, if the question is unclear.

For all these reasons, answering very poorly written questions is not a good use of your time.

Comment: If your looking for karma, votes, score, or the admiration of your peers you shouldn't even be reading down voted questions. If you do not agree with the reason for the down vote and you believe you can help. Help.

Comment: What about answering a question that OP didn't put much effort into it, but your answer guides/gives them a way to start solving their problem? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134018/how-do-you-create-a-priority-queue-using-an-implementation-of-an-unordered-linke/26134106#26134106

Comment: @FunctionR That's a request for a complete tutorial, not for hints.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I never said OP wanted only hints, but that's what I gave him. So does your post here fit that kind of situation?

Comment: @FunctionR: I think Robert does not say you did a bad thing, he indicates that answering non-"-10-ed" questions is a _more rewarding_ alternative.

Comment: Regarding 2. just downvoting because you don't like a behavior. I don't like this much. If SO doesn't like it they should forbid it. This is IMO the darkest side of downvoting and I would completely ignore it. One can surely stand above such practices. Anyway I think that 4. is the most important point. Unclear questions are extremely difficult to answer correctly. Often the answer is pure guesswork.

Comment: The mere fact that you think you can give a meaningful answer shows that it's a meaningful question. This implies that the downvoters didn't try to understand the question, or were offended by a clash with their pet prejudices, or were bureaucratic tossers of a sort that abounds on SO. In these cases I both answer and vote the question up to mitigate their misconduct.

Answer (score 36):

Answering downvoted (even heavily downvoted questions) clearly isn't frowned upon by the StackOverflow staff, since there's a badge to reward providing a good (or at least heavily upvoted) answer to a bad (or at least heavily downvoted) question. The [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge.

[image: Reversal badge]

Comment: Note, however, that the `Reversal` badge is meant to reward *outstanding* answers to poor questions, as opposed to quick answers to... well, poor questions. As such, it's basically a race between the question losing visibility (or being deleted) and the answer gathering enough audience. That's the main reason why only a few of these badges were ever awarded on SO.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not just Stack Overflow staff who issue upvotes and downvotes.

Answer (score 31):

**No, please do not try to answer questions that are about to be closed for only the sake of reputation.** That's actually one of the problems we are trying to solve here.

There are other things taking place under the hood that you may not have enough reputation to see, and by that I mean pending close votes. If a question is heavily downvoted, chances are these close votes you cannot see are also piling up as well.

In this situation, answering such a question becomes *really* tricky if you want to go in the right direction, for the benefit of both the site and the questioner. If the question is low-quality, you should not, I repeat, *not*, try to quickly answer it for the sake of reputation.

That's because this strategy, when applied against low-quality questions, does not benefit the site first-hand, but only the answerer (and many users have taken such a habit lately), and therefore some of us (including myself, I must admit) will unfortunately *downvote* such quick answers on sight.

All in all, if you are trying to answer such a question, keep in mind your answer should pretty much be irreproachable in order to prevent the effect I mentioned above. Sometimes, editing the question so it becomes more understandable can help.

Comment: I don't think most users like the asker here are trying to answer quickly _just_ to gain rep; they're trying to help the OP. At first glance, it seems like helping askers is exactly what this site is about, and posting answers is the best way to do that. It's only after you've been here for a while that you realize that you're mostly just feeding help vampires and/or nitwits who won't understand your answer, or that the real purpose of this site is providing a database of answered good questions and directly helping people is secondary.

Comment: @abarnert, our specific questioner says *Since I am a new user such questions can be a good opportunity to gain some reputation.* I think they're pretty lucid about the balance of power between rep gain and helping others :)

Comment: My point is that your answer sounds like rep is the only thing he, or people like him, care about; framing a response in terms of "don't be a rep whore" may not be as effective as "don't be a a rep whore, and _also_, here's what the site is really about, and here's why you're not helping anyone even though you think you are." There's nothing wrong with your answer, there could just be more to it.

Comment: But now that I think about it some more, Robert Harvey pretty much covered all that, so I guess it's not essential for you to cover all the same ground…

Comment: @abarnert, indeed. My answer was more focused about the close votes the questioner, being a self-admitted beginner, might not see. Then again, I only mentioned reputation once in my third paragraph, and I did not accuse anybody of whoring anything. I just wanted to point out that quick answers to bad questions should be discouraged (because they recursively perpetuate both bad questions and quick, would-be useful answers that recursively perpetuate...)

Comment: Actually Frederic you mention rep in your first sentence, in bold. "Do not... answer questions... for only the sake of reputation. That's actually one of the problems we are trying to solve here". I think you could word it more carefully. Just IMHO.

Comment: @Mark, ah, true :) I'm at a loss to word it better, though. An alternative, *please do not try to answer questions that are about to be closed, even if it looks like a good opportunity to gain reputation*, which borrows the questioner's words themselves, feels harsher to me...

Answer (score 14):

**IF** the question has undeserved downvotes (you can generally tell because there's an incorrect negative comment below it with lots of upvotes -- by "incorrect" I mean that the commenter is showing their own lack of knowledge on the subject, not anything wrong with the question -- then the other downvotes are probably piling on without thinking), and your expertise allows you to understand and answer the question, go ahead.

But, if you think the question meets the criteria for a downvote (it is poorly written, off topic, or especially if it is LAZY), then do not reward bad asking behavior with an answer.  Add your downvote and move on to find someone who respects your time by putting time into their question.

Comment: ++ for this *"move on to find someone who respects your time by putting time into their question."*

Answer (score 7):

Originally this was a comment but I the more I think about it I believe it is the answer:

If your looking for karma, votes, score, or the admiration of your peers you shouldn't even be reading down voted questions. If you do not agree with the reason for the down vote and you believe you can help. Help.

Answer (score 1):

Downvoted question are often so unclear or otherwise badly posed that it is extremely difficult to answer them with a good answer. I often see answers that are either trivial or just guesswork or opiniated. However I will never downvote them just because I don't like people answering poor question - I'm not such a person. But I will downvote them if they are bad.

General principle: **I judge the answer by how good (useful, ..) it answers the question regardless of the score of the question.**

And I answer poor questions only if I'm sure I understand the question and find it worthwhile to answer. But then I will also improve the question afterwards to get it to the standards of SO (polishing a pearl..). Unfortunately I cannot make the downvoters come back and rethink their vote so the downvotes usually stay.

Reasons why so few people answer poor questions with good answers although part or full answers are given in comments include that a) people are not sure if they can answer a poor question well and b) people don't want to spent the time answering a question that is not likely to attract many viewers, even may be deleted. Fear of unjustified downvotes might also play a role but shouldn't in my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to me that the real issue in answering this question is not about rep whoring. It is how well you can actually answer the question. If you think that you can write a good answer to someone's question -- whether or not it is a good question -- then it seems reasonable to do so whether or not it will garner reputation. Certainly a question which happens to be downvoted, but which is a good question that you think you can answer well, is a question worth answering.

As the other comments here suggest, this is not always a situation that applies. Many questions that are downvoted are indeed unintelligible or otherwise bad questions for which writing an answer, even a well-written, correct answer, is not of much help to even the confused person who asked the question. In this case, many users (including myself) would not bother to try to answer the question not out of spite or a desire to maintain proper etiquette and avoid rep whoring, but because answering a very confused question is not a good use of time or energy.

I suggest to answer questions (or not) based on how much knowledge you will be likely to impart with your answer, and not on the question's score or whether or not it you can earn reputation from it.

Answer (score -13):

As you can see if you visit stackoverflow often, many people do this intentionally.

This is called rep whoring. By doing this often, people gain rep fast. It works so well people often race to answer the worst of questions. I guarantee you in most of the cases your answer will be heavily upvoted.

But if you even remotely care about quality over quantity on this site, I suggest you downvote the question, mark it as low quality or being a duplicate, and move on. You won't gain rep, but you'll help to make the site a better place.

Comment: that is not rep-whoring...and people dont really gain that reputation because poor questions and closed and deleted - therefore all the reputation temporarily gained is lost anyway.

Comment: In an ideal world, poor questions get closed and deleted. But stackoverflow is not perfect.

Comment: Few questions that are closed actually get deleted, so your point about them losing reputation is moot.