# Handling answers to XY problems

Tags: discussion, specific-question, xy-problem

The specific question I have a concern with is [Optional instance of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799717/optional-instance-of-a-class#comment42173543_26799717). It's well-established that people who run across a problem often ask about Y rather than X, because they don't understand X well enough. It appears to me that what OP is asking for (how to create an "optional" object) is not what he really wants, but an attempted solution to his real problem. A high-rep user in the comments and the accepted answer suggests using `new` (manual memory management is frowned upon in modern C++) and it clearly satisfies the question and the OP, but probably gives the wrong lesson to OP and future visitors.

They learn:

- This answer does what I want. I don't have to care about modern C++ idioms or how to reconsider the structure of my program.
- My question was answered, I don't have to bother editing my question.

The accepted answerer even admits in the comments "Keep in mind that boost::optional, which is mentioned in another answer, is way more elegant. My solution is ugly.", which leads me to [Is it ok to answer downvoted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272422/is-it-ok-to-answer-downvoted-questions). However, the question isn't downvoted but I still think that some bullet points apply:

[Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272424/3920237):

> *[..]*
>
> 2. The community doesn't like people answering bad questions, and may downvote your answer just because of this.
> 3. When a person asks an unclear question, it's often indicative that they won't understand your answer, even if you understand their
>      question.
> 4. You can often be answering the wrong question, if the question is unclear.

Thankfully, another answerer which suggests a much better solution is being upvoted, but because it relies on a third party library, I suspect that it's ignored by OP either because they can't use the library or they don't understand how to use it (circling back to XY problem.)

Should I:

- Vote to close as *unclear what you're asking*? In the comments:

  > Me: What are you really trying to do?
  >
  > OP: only create and use thomas if there is an argument in outputtype2.
  >
  > Me: @OP No, I asked what are you really trying to do. This is what you
  >   think the appropriate solution to your real problem is but it probably
  >   isn't. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

  OP hasn't responded to my comment, leading me to suspect that there won't be any clarification in the question. And the question isn't exactly unclear - it's answerable in its current state.
- Downvote the answer? Downvoting an answer just because I don't like the question doesn't seem right. Though you could argue it's not useful because of the quip about manual memory management.
- Get over it? Maybe I'm just grouchy.