# Should I flag a answer that is answering something whats not the question about?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I had already many times flagged answers as not an answer which were declined as every answer is an answer, doesn't matter how bad they are.(Discussed multiple times on this meta)

Now I'm intended to flag this as not an answer as it is an answer which has nothing to do with the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167093/2003898

But remembering earlyer discussions, I kept in my mind.... Anyway it is still an answer.

(The OP is asking of a way to write a own macro which is expanding include file names, and the linked answer is answering how to write a platform independend wrapper for use of mkdir. quite funny and it is even an answer. But not to the aksed question...)

So should I just down vote it, or is it this kind of answer, which is allowed to be flagged as no answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)

Comment: see also: [Handling answers to XY problems](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276287/handling-answers-to-xy-problems)

Comment: @gnat: I can't deny that this appears to be duplicate OP. BUT: It is not duplicate of the first you have linked.

Comment: okay retracted my vote for first one. Consider [edit]ing the question to help readers understand the difference

Comment: "not an answer" is for things that aren't answers. "Rubbish answer" is what down votes are for. (With a special mention for _harmful_ or _offensive 'answers' which should be removed ASAP)

Answer (score 4):

You down vote it, and consider leaving a comment (like you've done) if you think it may be salvageable.

It is an answer, just a bad one - so down voting is the correct procedure. Once it goes negative (I'm not sure of the exact criteria) then higher privileged users can vote to delete it.