# Is it OK to answer a downvoted question with no obvious close reason?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

After I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34319608/1361506) a commenter questioned why I would bother to answer a question "that can be answered simply by reading the documentation".

[Is it ok to answer downvoted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272422/1361506) has an extensive discussion about answering bad/downvoted questions, but seems to focus more 
on questions that are unclear, or lack the information to answer them.

In this case, the question is very specific and clear, but the answer could easily be found by reading the javadoc.

I can't think of an applicable close reason for this question, but it's a poster child for a downvote due to the "This question does not show any research effort" part of the mouseover text.

Should I delete my answer and vote to close the question with a custom close reason along the lines of "Doesn't show any effort",
so that it can be deleted, or just leave it?

### Edit 1

There seems to be a lot of concern that I would post an answer that effectively boils down to "RTFM, it's right here".

My first thought was that a question this basic would surely have been asked and answered multiple times before, so I just needed to find an appropriate duplicate so I could vote to close. After all, doing something one time in the future after a delay is not exactly an uncommon situation.

However, a google search on "schedule a task to run one time with java" came back with a link to the [Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), a bunch of links about scheduling a task to run periodically.

Since there didn't seem to be any duplicate already in existence, I went ahead and answered the question, so that future googlers would see something more useful for this specific situation.

### Edit 2

I'm not asking for a new close reason, or a "no comment" close reason.  I'm perfectly happy to create a custom "off-topic" close reason, or just use "too broad" like everyone else did.

I'm trying to ask whether or not I should leave an answer on a bad question, or go ahead and delete my answer so that the question can be automatically deleted due to its high negative vote count.

### Edit 3

The general consensus seems to be that any answer on a bad question is not a good idea.  Rather than trying to fix the OP's question (which has been deleted), I just went ahead and [wrote my own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34324082/1361506), so that I could put a proper answer on it.

**TL;DR**: When is it justified to answer a bad question?

Comment: SO's guidelines have always made it clear that these questions shouldn't be asked, and that they don't belong on the site.  There has also never been a valid close reason for them, so there is no way to prevent people from answering them even though the site's official guidelines say that they shouldn't be asked.  Since people are both not supposed to ask them, but we're not allowed to stop people from answering them, it's rather conflicting as to what should happen.  As far as what does happen, people answer them anyway, the question and answer get upvotes, and the site gets worse as a result

Comment: So stack overflow is a documentation reading service now? Documentation that can be found with a simple google search?

Comment: @redFIVE That's not new, it's pretty much always been the case.

Comment: Its getting especially bad now. Answering these horrible questions only encourages more of the same

Comment: @Servy Could you point to where it states that in the guidelines?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The first line in "how to ask" is "Search, and research".  It's always been a premise that questions should be well researched, so a question that is trivially answered by googing itself clearly wouldn't qualify.  And the whole mission of the site has been to be a quality resource for future readers, expanding the scope of accessible information accessible to programmers.  Just duplicating information already readily accessible is not serving that goal.

Comment: @Servy There is a difference between a *"good question"* and a *"valid question"*. These types of questions, while not good, are not directly stated that they [should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What annoys me when people answer questions like this is that the answer that is obviously correct often gets upvoted, thus making the question require delete votes to be deleted rather than being automatically deleted a few weeks/months later by the automated script.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The whole premise of SO is to be a place where you only have quality questions, so yes, on SO if a question isn't a good question then it's not a valid question.  As for the list of things to avoid, that's not a comprehensive list, it's just the most common mistakes that people make.

Comment: I would only answer an RTFM question like that if I felt I could provide value beyond just reading the manual.  Saying "well method X does what you asked for, but due to gotcha Y you probably want Z instead" can be useful if the documentation doesn't say as much.  Just know that the question might not last long...

Comment: @Servy *"if a question isn't a good question then it's not a valid question"* No that's incorrect, while yes our goal is to provide quality questions and answers, it's not the rules of this site. I'd advise you to review the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Closing and deleting is for invalid questions, where voting is the basis for quality ones. All questions which are not good does not imply that they are invalid and should be removed/closed.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek low quality questions get sent to a queue to be deleted, so we certainly want low quality questions deleted. i guess you can argue whether or not the should also be closed. I don't think the close reason used fits this question at all, but i do think it's a question that should be deleted.

Comment: I don't think i would have closed this question. If going to the documentation for the mentioned method/class clearly explained how to accomplish what was being asked, i would downvote and leave a comment linking to docs, otherwise i'd not vote at all and possibly provide an answer if i feel i could provide an answer that would be very useful. I'm not familiar with java so i don't know which of the two this question would fall under.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The [roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/241526) has no qualms deleting questions are just low quality. (Votes can qualify a question for deletion, irrespective of close-worthiness.)

Comment: @Louis So why doesn't it remove questions with a 0 score and a > 0 score or accepted answer?

Comment: To avoid removing useful content. At that point it would need to be reviewed by humans to make sure it isn't useful content. If we've already downvoted the question, it is deemed not useful, but if it has an upvoted answer, deleting the question would be possibly deleting useful content (the answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I close voted that question as too broad and as I happened to be the fifth voter that question is now closed. I could also have chosen Unclear.

It is not that much interesting to have a question that isn't much more as *I want to use X to achieve Y, how?*. That is not a question, that is a requirement or as task description.

It is not hard to make a simple question a little bit interesting.

*I used X with arguments foo and bar to achieve Y because the javadoc seemed to imply that it is a possible way to do that. However the outcome was Z. Can I get Y with X?*

Those are practical problems encountered by programmers where future visitors will benefit from the answers as they might make the same mistake/run into the same issue.

It is not forbidden to answer down voted questions. However, questions that really should be closed because they are too broad or unclear should be close voted and/or down voted if they lack any more detail than just the name of class from the documentation.

Comment: It sounds like what you're suggesting here is that rather than answer the OP's question, I instead write my own non-crappy question that is more generally applicable, answer **that**, and then close the original as a duplicate of my own question.

Comment: Yeah, closing as a duplicate is also fine @azurefrog and I don't mind if you didn't find a good dupe that you either create one or edit the question of the OP into shape.

Comment: Well, the origin question got deleted, so I just went ahead and wrote my own.  Thanks for the feedback.