# Suggested edit rejected, I am struggling to understand what I did wrong

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10682345) where in the OP code there was no indentation.

The edit was approved by two and rejected by three including the author. I also edited the question title to make it more to the point.

Later a similar edit to the title was accepted. And the saddest bit is that the question still has bloating non-formatted code which is hard to read.

1. Is my edit really overly minor?
2. Or where there other reasons to reject this edit?
3. Is basic code formatting in questions important?

PS: I read an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) and it seems that editing non-formatted code to add formatting is ok.

Also in my edit it was suggested that I should suggest edits in comments to the author. I've done it many times and mostly authors choose to ignore these suggestions.

Currently I've made 4 edits with 2 accepted and 2 rejected and I am confused - should I just continue my trial and error method?

**Update**

Now I notice that it looks like I removed altogether relevant bits of code. But parts of code denoted *html* and *config* where not there when I started editing.

All I did is remove whitespaces in the first code snippet and rephrase the title. (At least if we assume I am sane =))

Comment: The author of the post always wins in suggested edit cases. You changed an awful lot of code on that question. That should really not be done.

Comment: @rene  About that - I really did not. I also look at edit history and see that I removed all code, but I didn't. See the state of the question now. That is how it looked when I started editing it.

Comment: @rene to clarify there was no `html` part and no `config` part.

Comment: Looks like you're a victim of an edit conflict: the OP *added* some code to the question while you were editing it, so your suggestion lacked the additional code. In that case, it's not surprising the OP rejected your edit (and his vote is binding). Don't worry, you're sane :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski so that can happen. But suppose OP didn't add more code would my edit then be usefull?
Should I resuggest it?

Comment: @Olga yes, making code more readable certainly improves the question. And this formatting was pretty awful. I've fixed it to spare you the trouble of going through a review again (with uncertain results as some reviewers may disapprove whitespace-only edits).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thank you very much. You are great!

Comment: @honk showing a masterclass? =) Thanks for the edits.

Comment: @Olga: No way! ;) I just love to improve things. At least I hope I'm doing improvements :)

Comment: @honk from my pov you are.

Comment: @Olga Your edit was rejected by two people, not three. The author and the `Community` user is one user.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Why doesn't the system detect edit conflicts (unless they can be auto merged) and prevent the edit from going through in the first place? I'd always assumed it did.

Comment: I don't see what's not clear about the edit rejection here? You removed *far* too much out of the question; the specific rejection reason for this type of edit is 'edit conflicts with author's intent'. You also failed to remove other issues such as noise.

Comment: @cybermonkey please clarify, what do you mean by noise? As it has been explained in the question I didn't realise how much I removed until I actually posted the question. See update.

Comment: @Olga Like `Thank You`, you should always remove stuff like that.

Comment: @cybermonkey my bad - missed it.

Comment: @Random832 well, it *kinda* does... When you edit a post, and this post changes, you get the "new version available" bar above the post. You may well not notice it, and if you click it you lose your changes and have to start over. There's no auto-merge AFAIK. This is less than ideal.

Comment: You could still click the button immediately before that message shows up. I'm thinking the way Wikipedia does it, it doesn't accept the change at all until you've submitted a new form which displayed the diff of the new change vs your version.

Comment: IMO you whacked way to much out of the question so OP rejected your edit. Forgive my seeming coldness, but...so? Try not to take it too seriously. StackOverflow is of no particular importance - it's just a Q&A site where you can answer questions, edit stuff, etc. It's not IMPORTANT in the same way as, say, a clogged toilet is important. Move on. Get over it. Go cure the common cold. Play with your dog/cat/goat. Wipe a crying child's nose. Do something else, which may or may not be more meaningful (in either the big or small sense) than this. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis hey we already collectively figured out it was an editing race. So everything is swell. I'll go pat the cat though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You changed pretty much in the code of that edit. At least if the preview the reviewers saw is similar to what I see:

[image: edit preview]

If the OP rejects a suggested edit you're out of luck anyway; they have a binding vote. Notice that you were right on track to get your edit approved so I assume those reviewers were able to judge your edit as being a much needed improvement.

Based on the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34462454/revisions), it looks like both the OP and one other editor had more luck with getting their edits in, which look familiar with what you tried.

In general try to edit as much as possible in one go. White space-only edits are badly digested by the reviewers so make sure if you do that to include other fixes as well. If you edit code make sure you don't change the intent of the OP. I'm very hesitant in general to touch code during my edits, I keep it to layout.

On [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9124134) I would have refrained from editing, but you missed also to capitalize the I in the title, and I think doing a lower case on `COMPLETELY` would have been better as well as adding the a in *for certain container?* to *for a certain container?* ...

Comment: Thanks for explaining on the other rejected edit too.

Comment: You're giving contradictory advice here. You say @Olga changed too much, but also that she should try to edit as much as possible in one go? It's unclear what message  you want her to take away from this answer. Personally, I (and two out of three of the reviewers, besides the question asker) thought her edit was fine; she removed HTML blocks that were totally irrelevant to the question and fixed the hideous formatting of what remained; the only thing arguably wrong about the edit was that it was a waste since it was made to an unsalvageably bad post.

Comment: @MarkAmery except that I wouldn't remove code however useless it may look. Aren't bad question worth editing? Maybe the author will learn from example?

Comment: @MarkAmery Hmm, it was not my intent to be contradictory. What I meant to say that editing so much in the code, how bad the code may seem, isn't   always received well. Let me see if I can clarify that bit...

Comment: There's a distinction to be made between editing the MEANING of the post too much (editing code etc.), versus making as many STYLISTIC changes as possible (fixing grammar/capitalisation/presentation etc.).

Comment: @Olga *"Aren't bad question worth editing?"* - That's a current point of debate on Meta. See, for instance, [*Requesting a "Stop Polishing Turds" Edit Suggestion Reject Reason*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260302) and [*Why is there not an edit-rejection reason to cover turd-polishing?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307482). Most reviewers, me included, *won't* reject an edit just because the underlying post is bad, but many of us think that suggesting such edits are a waste of (mostly your) time. If you disagree, by all means keep doing your best to improve these posts.

Comment: I notice the OP actually did a **Reject and Edit**, not  simple **Reject**.  If he added new material at that time, wouldn't it look like Olga had *deleted* that material?  If so, then I would call that a bug.