# How is this not worthy of an edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Consider this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12618804

Just check the edit. That is enough of a change, makes the post more readable and improves the grammar aspect too.

How is that not something Stack Overflow would appreciate? I'm just curios IF: I shouldn't edit like this OR: This *should* be an accepted edit.

Comment: The question is closed, just removing `I don't know its syntax in C#. please help.` doesn't really make it a good question. Don't waste yours (and others) time on questions that aren't going to be valuable.

Comment: @TZHX the question was closed based on a state of the question that is not the current one. I dont think it should be closed. Also I fixed some grammatical errors

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: @TZHX "I have some string and I want to hash it with SHA-256  hash function" to "I have some string and I want to SHA-256-hash it in C#". No?

Comment: Its much more readable like this imho

Comment: @Mafii After your edit it wouldn't even contain a question. Your changes are absolutely not acceptable.

Comment: In your opinion, perhaps, but in mine it reads as pretty much the same. I would even say, in my opinion, that the original structure is better.

Comment: IMO something between the two would be better "I want to hash a string with SHA256. How can I do this in C#?". But it was readable enough as-was. That said I'd probably have approved the edit: true, this was a minor change, but it was made in better faith than a lot of the 'formatting' edits that get submitted.

Comment: Someone once told this to me so I'm going to pass it to you now: *"Don't waste time polishing a turd. If the question is good, then it's perfectly fine to make it better"*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ _"I don't know its C# syntax. Please help."_ isn't a question either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing something known as "turd polishing". It's an old post, and your edit doesn't greatly improve the readability of the post. You also did't fix *all* the issues with the post: inline code to highlight random terms, tag in title (disputable), irrelevant tag.

[I have edited the post now, see the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16999361/revisions).

See also:

- [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)
- [Why is there not an edit-rejection reason to cover cleanups of off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307482/why-is-there-not-an-edit-rejection-reason-to-cover-turd-polishing)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I appreciate it. However, I disagree with the use of the word function. But thats just like my opinion, ye?

Comment: Well, the thing _is_ called a "cryptographic hash function". ;-)

Comment: True. @CodeCaster