# Can we have a suggested edit rejection reason for editing posts that are of very low quality?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, editing-help

Can we have a suggested edit rejection reason for editing posts that are of very low quality?

Caveat: I'm not referring to questions that are borderline ok and need a tidy up, I'm referring to questions like:

> My app not working plz help.

or answers like:

> how can i do this. show me.

When a question is such low quality that there is no way a person, other than the OP can edit it to make it on topic, often there will be suggested edits to improve grammar or worse still add tags (those these can be rejected using adding irrelevant tags).

[image]

The **causes harm** custom reason is not really suitable, as they're not causing harm, just wasting time and expecting a rep reward for editing crap that needs to be deleted.

It but may still fall into the **no improvement whatsoever**, as the post is unfit for the site.

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

[The answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307489/3956566) to this question - 
[Why is there not an edit-rejection reason to cover cleanups of off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307482/why-is-there-not-an-edit-rejection-reason-to-cover-turd-polishing) suggests that this would be the correct rejection message to give edit suggestions made to such low quality posts *(thanks to [Siguza](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2302862/siguza) for the link)*.

However,
This does not sit well with me, as it doesn't really provide guided feedback to the editor. I'm thinking of a way to  educate the suggested editor.

**editing very low quality posts**

> Editing very low quality posts is a wasted effort, as the post is likely to be deleted. It doesn't assist in improving the site, please edit a post that is ontopic.

We could add:

*It's a bit like painting out a suite on the Titanic.*

*Not a dup, this is a feature-request.*

Comment: The other thing that really annoys me if when people edit tags and leave atrocious grammar.

Comment: They will lose any reputation earned by editing once the question is deleted.

Comment: @user000001 yeh, but it's annoying, as I want a decent edit rejection reason.

Comment: Technically, it does cause harm. In many cases pending flags are marked as helpful and cleared after sny edit, so any progress (like recommend delete votes in the LQ queue) need to start over.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes I was wondering about that, but that is also a complex explanation to a user who is suggesting poor edits. It would be better to have a stock reason there.

Comment: @Yvette the biggest concern I have with the idea is how much would it be misused relative to the educational opportunity?  As a community, we have enough trouble agreeing on exactly what "low quality" means.  So while you potentially educate some users, you potentially have reviews who use this reason where it wasn't intended and then are confused by the reason because the post isn't low quality in their mind (and maybe in the minds of many members of the community).  And all of this assumes the editors even read the reject reason to begin with

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307482) it says such edits should be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever", so technically this question is a dupe. However, I disagree with that because "no improvement whatsoever" will not teach the editor _anything_ about why their edit was rejected, so it's a very bad reject reason to choose, and it would make much sense to have a separate one for turd polishing. (Feel like adding that to the question, @Yvette?)

Comment: (off: so hard to resist posting an answer: `how can i do this. show me.`)

Comment: @Siguza yes I will and thanks for the link and feedback

Comment: @ppeterka yes, I would like that, but it could go either way ;)

Comment: I'd say "clearly conflicts with author's intent" is appropriate. The author didn't intend to write a coherent question, so an editor shouldn't try to change that.

Comment: @SeinopSys that is hilarious

Comment: This is [\[status-de-facto-declined\] on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/requesting-a-stop-polishing-turds-edit-suggestion-reject-reason).

Comment: "You can't polish a turd, but you can roll it in glitter". So I call this type of edit a glitter-roll. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: [Mythbusters would beg to differ with the first part of that assertion.](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/polishing-a-turd-minimyth/)

Comment: @Martha too scared to click on that link ;)

Comment: @Yvette: [here, this one's just a picture of the result.](https://crossderry.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/projectoutput.png)

Comment: @Martha omg you really can polish a turd. This upsets the entire premise of meta .... O>O

Comment: I use the custom reject reason (aka "causes harm") and then explain that such posts should be deleted, not edited. I [once posted a request to rename "causes harm" to "other"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274093/168333). But don't worry too much about what it is called; just try to give the right feedback to the editor.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I just saw this comment -  FYI https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356344/can-we-change-the-causes-harm-reason-to-custom-reason-for-rejecting-suggested-ed

Comment: 4 years later, if someone notices: yes, this is still a problem reviewers face in the review queue that is left unaddressed. I usually choose causes harm and carefully explain that the post in not worth the time, but a lot of the times I do not have canned comments at my fingertips. A canned reason (even if it is treated like one of the existing reasons by the database) would be a time-saver (we want more reivewes, not less, I hope?)